# How to set cloud functions configs of a transferred firebase project in android studio?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I’m deploying two Firebase cloud functions for a project (Project #1). Project #1 has been transferred to another Firebase Console project (Project #2). I’ve coded cloud functions to send notifications. On Project #1, Notifications were working correctly, but when I transferred the project, now Notification service does not work at all!. Does anyone know how to change the configuration such that notifications work on Project #2?
I think the problem is that the server key of Project #1 is already in the cloud config function but I’m not sure how to make the server key for this new project #2.

Let me explain in detail; First I created a project connected to Firebase, and I set up all cloud functions and notifications were working correctly. Then as I needed to interact with another android project, I had to move my own to another Firebase project. Now, with the same cloud functions and configs which were working, I cannot make the notifications work. DO you see what the problem is?

I’ve provided you with the index.js file:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationPending = functions.database.ref('/Appointment/{id}').onCreate((snapshot,context) => {

    const receiverId =snapshot.val().keyUser;
    console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);
    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title : 'New Appointment',
            body : 'You have a new Pending Appointment',
            sound : 'default'
        }
    };

    return admin.database().ref('/Users/'+receiverId).once('value').then(snap=>{
        const token = snap.child("fcm_token").val();
                    console.log("token: ", token);

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
    });
});


exports.sendNotificationCompleted = functions.database.ref('/Appointment/{id}').onUpdate((change,context) => {

    const after=change.after.val();
    const before=change.before.val();
    const receiverId =after.keyUser;
    console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);
    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title : 'New Completed Appointment',
            body : 'You have a Completed Appointment.You can upload invoice/prescription.',
            sound : 'default'
        }
    };
    if(after.status==='COMPLETED' && before.status!==after.status){

         return admin.database().ref('/Users/'+receiverId).once('value').then(snap=>{
                const token = snap.child("fcm_token").val();
                            console.log("token: ", token);

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
            });
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using a "server key" anywhere in the code.

Comment: I just guessed the problem it caused.I mean configuration of previous project doesn't work for current project.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: First, I create project #1 in firebase console and deploy these functions.My app works fine and the notifications have sent.But When I connect my app to project #2 of firebase console, the notification haven't sent.The project #2 contains to app